# Hashing algorithm without the avalanche effect

Tags: hashing

I know that one of the most important features of hashing algorithms, is that minor changes in the input should reflect great change in the hash itself ([the avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect)), but I'm currently searching for a solution that doesn't implement this.

I've read [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25730/what-are-some-hashes-that-do-not-exhibit-the-avalanche-effect) on the cryptography stackexchange, but it doesn't seem to offer exactly what I need.

I still need the input to be obscured so that reversion is impossible/improbable, but I'd like for similar input values to output similar hashes.

I imagine an algorithm with something like this (pseudo-example):

```
Input: Is this possible?
Output: 5e2a9d8a8f02c07c20142a571f1785c2

Input: Is this impossible?
Output: 5e2a9d8a8f02c07c20142a671f1785d2
```

Does something like this exist at all?

Comment: You want something like [locality-sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing).

Comment: Yes @Deduplicator that is exactly what I want! Feel free to post an answer I can accept :)

Comment: Just add the character values?

Comment: @MartinMaat If I added the ASCII values of the characters the sentence `Power to the people` would be 1814 and `I love giant tigers!` would be 1825 so those sentences would be considered **very** similar (although they aren't!)

Comment: ASCII characters don't reflect the difference you're looking for very well (e.g. 'a' to 'A' is a larger change than 'a' to 'x'). Do the strings have any structure you could leverage? Do they have a maximum length? How large is your alphabet? Do you have a set of possible words? Is 'were you there' and 'you were there' very similar or very different (i.e. how important is the position of words)? I think order is extremely difficult, because you need to include a character's/word's position without accidentally giving some parts of the string more weight than others. How about 'WERE YOU THERE'?